# Security and authentication methods I use

Tags: c#, wcf, security, session

I am not a programmer, but for some reason I do program here at work to do some apps that makes out job easier.  Anyway, this "some apps" has grown bigger in years. I've always had problems in understanding security or authentication related things, so I do it my way (which is indeed way way way far from being right). I use C#, mostly with client/server apps using WCF.

The issue now is in my methods in WCF.  All of them are similar to this:

```
public Employee AddEmployee(Guid sessionID, Employee emp)
{
    Session session = Common.CheckSession(sessionID);

    // do stuff
 }
```

As you can see, the sessionID is passed to every call to the WCF.  This ID is generated once the user login using another WCF method.  A row in the database is created and the 'CheckSession', which is called in every single method checks if the session is valid and if the user is allowed and so on. The connection is secured using SSL.

How wrong is this?  Can I just keep do it for now?  Or should I just stop it because it is so messed up, and start figuring out the right way of doing it?

Comment: Quite wrong, yes, no, yes - it may be better to integrate with existing authentication system instead - generally it may not be possible to verify if guid have correct permissions (also you indeed store it and check on every request).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "existing authentication system ", define that please. and the guid is sent with every single call to the WCF service.

Comment: If you are in Windows world you may authenticate every request instead of passing custom token... But otherwise looks as secure as regular ASP.Net session state... It just feels wrong since you have authentication and functionality merged into single list of arguments...

Answer (score 0):

if you squint your eyes and turn your head to the side a bit, this is kind of how authentication works.

Except, WCF uses an encrypted layer to send messages so no one can spy on your session / authentication / data information

It does a similar check, not per call, but it hooks the calls (which you could do too) right at the beginning, checks the authentication, then passes it on if its allowed to.

Thats just for authentication (working out that you are who you say you are).  Security, whether a particular user is allowed to perform  particular actions is controlled through things like "Roles".  But you may have to build in even more checks if you have more fine grained security concerns.

Now inventing that yourself? Not a good idea. Too easy to have holes your method.

Comment: Thanks, any tips on where to start to fix this? a sample of how to achieve this using built-in stuff that comes with WCF?

Comment: I found WCF one of the more involved techs to get your head around this stuff.  You can use the more modern WebAPI if it suits, its a bit simpler.  WCF is a lot more extensive which kind of forces you to have to understand things a bit better.  From memory, I mainly used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779(v=vs.110).aspx  and a lot of googling for examples / clarifications / and configurations that matched what I was trying to achieve ( theres lots out there)